# How to build website build with Oracle-jet

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design, developer-tools, vs-web-site-project, oracle-jet

> Anybody working in **oracle jet** please help me to develop a website for my application.
>   Is this best for Website building? please tell me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will get all graph and ready made components and few commands will help you to create production ready code

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/globalGetStarted.html

go to this page use Command Line Tooling option

Answer (score 0):

Use the cookbook from oracle for oracle jet .
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html

set up a project as per requirement and start working on it. not sure whats you exact requirement as per question. 
Oracle jet is good for building SPA, it has built components makes web development easy rather than one coding their components.